# Excel vba range .find function prevent return back to first cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have values on cells L7,L12,L13,L14
with below code I can find values and collect it to range. But during .find loop function search again reach the first result and exit .find function.
problem is I receive range L12,L13,L14, L7
normally L7 must be at beginning.

how can I solve it?
Can I prevent .find to return back first cell or can i sort the range I got with .find ?

```
Function FindAll1(rngLookIn As Range, LookFor) As Range


Dim rv As Range, c As Range, FirstAddress As String
With rngLookIn
    Set c = .Find(LookFor, After:=Range("L2"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = c.Address
        Set rv = c
        Do
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then Set rv = Application.Union(rv, c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With
Set FindAll1 = rv
End Function
```

This is my code call function

```
   Set searchitem = FindAll1(arama, aranan)

    If Not searchitem Is Nothing Then

        For Each g In searchitem.Cells
```

my code starts here but It comes L12 first instead of L7 from searchitem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
Function FindAll1(rngLookIn As Range, LookFor) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range, FirstAddress As String
    With rngLookIn
        Set c = .Find(LookFor, After:=.Cells(.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<--| force the passed range last cell as the one to start searching for -> this will make the first matching one as the first to be listed
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = c.Address
            Set rv = c
            Do
                Set rv = Application.Union(rv, c) '<--| first, update union
                Set c = .FindNext(c) '<--| then, seach next match
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> FirstAddress '<--| exit if reached the first match -> this will prevent adding first matching cell to union again 
        End If
    End With
    Set FindAll1 = rv
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
Function FindAll1(rngLookIn As Range, LookFor) As Range
Dim rv As Range, c As Range, FirstAddress As String
With rngLookIn
    Set c = .Find(LookFor, After:=Range("L2"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    FirstAddress = c.Address
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        Do
            If rv Is Nothing Then
                Set rv = c
            Else
                Set rv = Union(rv, c)
            End If
            Set c = .FindNext(c)

        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With
Set FindAll1 = rv
End Function
```